# Using netty with business logic

Tags: java, netty

I'm not too experienced using netty and have a question about the documentation of [***ChannelPipeline***](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html). Here is what it is about exactly:

```
 static final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(16);
 ...

 ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

 pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MyProtocolDecoder());
 pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MyProtocolEncoder());

 // Tell the pipeline to run MyBusinessLogicHandler's event handler methods
 // in a different thread than an I/O thread so that the I/O thread is not blocked by
 // a time-consuming task.
 // If your business logic is fully asynchronous or finished very quickly, you don't
 // need to specify a group.
 pipeline.addLast(group, "handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());
```

I don't quite understand the `MyBusinessLogicHandler` class. Should it implement `DuplexChannelHandler` or something different? For instance, in my particular case I have the following class:

```
public class Packet{}
```

I want to decode some byte sequence into `Packet`, give to `MyBusinessLogicHandler` which produces some `Packet`. and then encode it into a byte stream again to send back to a client. I currently see it like this:

```
public class MyBusinessLogicHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<MyModel>{
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet msg){
         Packet rslt = null;
         //Do some complicated business logic
         ctx.write(rslt);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a common way to do things in netty. Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap. That's totally fine and correct way for implementing `MyBusinessLogicHandler`. You don't need `DuplexChannelHandler` as in your pipeline you have already `MyProtocolEncoder` (that I suppose implements `ChannelOutboundHandler`).
So when you call `ctx.write(rslt)` you trigger write event for outbound handlers.

`DuplexChannelHandler` would be useful only in case you would like to implement both encoder and decoder in the same class. For example, you may do that by joining `MyProtocolEncoder` and `MyProtocolDecoder`.